# Null Pointer Exception on Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm trying to create an app which allows users to screenshot the current view. I'm using the following code to do so.

```
View content = ((Activity)ctx).findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
File file = new File("/sdcard/test.png");

try 
{
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
    ostream.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, i'm getting a Null Pointer Exception on the following line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
```

What would this mean, that the view is empty?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` before you can use that.  Then call `content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);` when you're done.